# What are the impacts of forcing garbage collection on live objects as well as long lived objects?

Tags: .net, object, static, garbage-collection

In .Net framework, garbage collection runs periodically and reclaim the memory or space allocated to dead objects. However if we want to force GC.Collect(), whether it affect live objects or it will reclaim only the space allocated to dead objects?

Also, what is the impact of forcing Garbage collection on long-lived objects such as static objects?

Answer (score 1):

The GC.Collect method just [forces garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_GC_Collect). That means that you force the garbage collector to do it's job now instead of some time in the future. But the job stays the same which means that it will not touch objects that are still in use.